# Modin library throws errors while doing simple pandas operation

Tags: python, pandas, modin

I came across modin library that is supposed to accelerate some pandas operation and started to test it.

While loading data with read_csv is significantly faster, simple conditional expressions that work perfectly in pure pandas, like:

```
    df.loc[df['Score'] > 8,'Score_T2B'] = 1
    df.loc[df['Score'] < 9,'Score_T2B'] = 0
```

throw many errors:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<ipython-input-21-0b842942ffac>", line 1, in <module>
    df.loc[df['Score'] > 8,'Score_T2B'] = 1

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\modin\pandas\indexing.py", line 251, in __setitem__
new_col[row_loc] = item

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1244, in __setitem__
setitem(key, value)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1221, in setitem
self.loc[key] = value

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 204, in __setitem__
indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 191, in _get_setitem_indexer
return self._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=axis, is_setter=True)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1285, in _convert_to_indexer
return self._get_listlike_indexer(obj, axis, **kwargs)[1]

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1092, in _get_listlike_indexer
keyarr, indexer, o._get_axis_number(axis), raise_missing=raise_missing

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1177, in _validate_read_indexer
key=key, axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)

KeyError: "None of [Index([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,\n       ...\n       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],\n      dtype='object', length=169815)] are in the [index]"
```

That is supposed to be a simple operation. Is there a work around or I just missed something other than loading:

```
  import modin.pandas as pm  
  df = pm.read_csv(input_file, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I found that modin's `read_csv` function does NOT work exactly like a pandas.read_csv drop in replacement. In particular, it doesn't do exception handling as well, and throws exceptions that would otherwise work with pandas.

Perhaps it's best to import both versions and fallback on pandas when this fails?

here is my importer

```
try:
    import modin.pandas as pd # claims to be 4X faster loading csvs, using all processor cores
    print('modin.pandas active')
except ImportError:
    import pandas as pd
```

Here is my example that failed to read_csv properly:

This causes a TypeError with modin, but no error with pandas. The file being loaded does not contain a column name `'IlmnID'`.

```
try:
    sample = pd.read_csv(part, index_col='IlmnID')
except ValueError:
    sample = pd.read_csv(part)
```

this works with modin.pd.read_csv, because there's no try/except wrapper

```
sample = pd.read_csv(part)
if 'IlmnID' in sample.columns:
    sample.set_index('IlmnID', inplace=True)
elif 'illumina_id' in sample.columns:
    sample.set_index('illumina_id', inplace=True)
    sample.rename(index={'illumin_id': 'IlmnID'}, inplace=True)
else:
    # assume first column
    guess_index = columns[0]
    sample.set_index(guess_index, inplace=True)
    sample.rename(index={guess_index: 'IlmnID'}, inplace=True)
```